# Load a dll containing windows dialogs in an MFC Application

Tags: visual-c++, dll, mfc

I am developing an app using `MFC`. I need to create a dll that contains two dialogs. The dialogs in the dll are registration and login dialogs. Then the dialogs in the dll will show in the `MFC` application. How can I load these dialogs from dll in my MFC Application.

Comment: You are talking about *Windows Forms*, but the question isn't tagged [.NET]. Which one is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have all your dialog resources in a separate DLL, a so called resource only DLL.

```
HINSTANCE h = LoadLibrary("myresources.dll") ;
AfxSetResourceHandle(h) ;
```

After that, the dialogs (as well as all other resources)  will be fetched from that dll instead of from your .exe.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to hold all resources in one dll. When your project will be getting bigger and you will have definitely more than two dll. It will be pain in the ass when you add new/remove control or something else to dialog and you will need to rebuild all project (because you will change your branch resource dll). It eats time...

Better solution to keep some main resources in resource.dll (that will not change so often) and all other controls keep in separate dll. You just need to follow that your resource id's of all your project must be different.

example:
test1.dll resource.h

```
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        10000
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         11000
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         12000
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           13000
```

test2.dl resource.h

```
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        14000
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         15000
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         16000
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           17000
```